# how to escape special chars when i need to send regular expression over json to my Rest Service

Tags: regex, json, rest

I need to send regular expression using json to my rest service.
But i found i need to kind of escape things like `\d{8}` in regular expression.

I tried to use `\\d\{8\}`, but the XSSFilter returns error saying it has multiple encoding in the incoming message.

I was intend to send something like 
`"ABC-DEF-\d{8}"` and i escaped as `"ABC-DEF-\\d\{8\}"`

I have done research on this question, but no get anything.

I digged into the Filter for my rest service. The security filter check the encoding of the json. It think \d{8} contains javascript. So it is insecure.

Comment: Please include the JS code you use and the JSON it produces.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: its simply a http post request with json as http body. json ooks like {"expression": "ABC-DEF-\d{8}"}

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You should only `\d`, you should not escape `{` and `}` that are part of a *limited* (also called *interval*, *range*) quantifier:

```
{"expression": "ABC-DEF-\\d{8}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is urlencode the data you want to send in json